# Python: pyodbc, Microsoft Access: update dates in table, using # date qualifier

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to update some records in a Microsoft Access database, using pyodbc in Python. I am struggling in updating date/time fields in Access, which would require a # date qualifier symbol in the sql statement.

A sample of a statement could be

`sql = '''UPDATE [TABLE] SET[STARTDATE]=#2018-10-25# WHERE[KEYCOLUMN]=12345;'''`

Using a parameter query, that would look like

```
sql = '''UPDATE [TABLE] SET[STARTDATE]=? WHERE[KEYCOLUMN]=?;'''
params = (#2018-10-25#, 12345)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

However, the execution crashes because of the required # symbols for the data qualifier. 
Also using the datetime library is not helpful, as the following parameters are also resulting in a failed execution:

```
params = (datetime.date(2018,10,25), 12345)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

What would be the correct syntax/workaround for updating DateTime fields, including blanking a DateTime field in an Access database?

**Error codes when trying different attempts (with the actual table names and field names, instead of the sample names used in above example)**:

When passing the date as a string

```
SQL: UPDATE [Status Scorecard] [IN:Start Execute] = ? WHERE [IN:ID]=?;
Params: ('2015-09-14', '47977')
Error:(<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement. (-3503) (SQLExecDirectW)'), <traceback object at 0x07E24120>)
```

When passing the data with # date delimiter symbol:

```
sql = '''UPDATE [Status Scorecard] [IN:Start Execute] = ? WHERE [IN:ID]=?;'''
params = (#2015-09-14#, '47977')
print(params)
r = axSCORECARD.updateSQL(sql, params)
```

The code does not run, as the # symbol is treated as a comment, resulting in a code syntax error.

When passing the data as a string, using the # date delimiter inside the string:

```
SQL: UPDATE [Status Scorecard] [IN:Start Execute] = ? WHERE [IN:ID]=?;
Params: ('#2015-09-14#', '47977')
Error:(<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement. (-3503) (SQLExecDirectW)'), <traceback object at 0x07E24148>)
```

When passing the date as a datetime.date call (after having added 'import datatime' to the script):

```
SQL: UPDATE [Status Scorecard] [IN:Start Execute] = ? WHERE [IN:ID]=?;
Params: (datetime.date(2015, 9, 14), '47977')
Error:(<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement. (-3503) (SQLExecDirectW)'), <traceback object at 0x07E240D0>)
```

Comment: Please provide the actual error messages. In a query using parameters, you should not need to use any delimiters, and just pass the values.

Comment: Also re: "blanking" have you tried passing `None` as the parameter value?

Comment: Erik, the error messages were added to the original question text.

Comment: Gord, thank you for you suggestion of using None. I did try it, but in combination with also providing true dates from some other DateTime fields, which still made the code to crash. But will give None an isolated test run.

Comment: @Bert - I don't see the SET keyword in your updated examples. (p.s. use `@` to reply to a commenter)

Comment: I don't think you need to put your dates between hash tags. Use single or double quotes.

Comment: @BertGeenen That's a plain syntax error. Your query in the added examples doesn't look anything like the queries above, and even those are invalid because they miss a space after `Set` and `Where`

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for pointing out the missing SET keyword. I must have deleted it while 'simplifying' the sql statement for pasting it into this question. Combined with your below answer with explanation and sample code, my update query does run properly and updated (and cleared) the dates as expected.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Eric, thank you for pointing out the syntax error. The sample query and the actual ones with the error results are indeed different, as I tried to illustrate the issue with the sample code, and added the 'true' error codes only afterwards. And indeed, to your point, the sample sql statements are missing the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash mark (`#`) delimiters are only required for date literals in the SQL command text itself. They are not required (and are in fact invalid) in a parameterized query.

This works, verified with pyodbc 4.0.24:

```python
sql = "UPDATE [Status Scorecard] SET [IN:Start Execute] = ? WHERE [IN:ID] = ?"
params = (datetime.date(2015, 9, 14), '47977')
crsr.execute(sql, params)
cnxn.commit()
```

result:

```
IN:ID  IN:Start Execute
-----  ----------------
47977  2015-09-14
```

To "blank out" the date, use `None`

```python
params = (None, '47977')
```

Comment: To "blank out" the date ... technically rendering it `NULL`.